# Send custom header in Socket.io-client

Tags: java, android, socket.io, socket.io-java-client

I have an issue while sending the custom header in [socket.io-client](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java). Everything is okay at server side integration/code because iOS code is working fine. Here is code which I have in iOS:

```
let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://server_url_here/")!, 
                            config: [.log(true), 
                                     .compress, .extraHeaders(["Authorization": "Bearer \(Defaults[.authToken])"])])
```

Now I tried the approach mentioned by socket.io-client documentation.Here is the code which I used:

```
final OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addNetworkInterceptor(new CustomHeaderInterceptor())
                    .build();

//options    
final IO.Options options = new IO.Options();

options.webSocketFactory = httpClient;
options.callFactory = httpClient;

//manager
Manager manager = new Manager(URI.create(Constants.BASEURL));
socket = manager.socket("/event/0", options);

socket.connect();
```

But this is giving the error in socket error handler:

> io.socket.engineio.client.engineioexception xhr post error

I tried with this below code as well but not working:

```
socket.io().on(Manager.EVENT_TRANSPORT, new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        Transport transport = (Transport) args[0];
        // Adding headers when EVENT_REQUEST_HEADERS is called
        transport.on(Transport.EVENT_REQUEST_HEADERS, new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                Map<String, List<String>> mHeaders = (Map<String, List<String>>)args[0];
                mHeaders.put("Authorization", Arrays.asList(auth_token_with_bearer));        
            }
        });
        transport.on(Transport.EVENT_RESPONSE_HEADERS, new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                Map<String, List<String>> headers = (Map<String, List<String>>)args[0];
                // access response headers
                String auth = headers.get("Authorization").get(0);


            }
        });
    }
});
```

I read many threads related to this issue but none of these are working for me. Please let me know where I'm wrong at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {

@Override
public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request original = chain.request();

    Request request = original.newBuilder()
        .header("User-Agent", "Your-App-Name")
        .header("Accept", "application/json")
        .header("your_header_key", "value")
        .method(original.method(), original.body())
        .build();

    return chain.proceed(request);
}
}

 OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();
```